# Android Java: Multiplayer Quiz Buzz In System with Minimal Lag?

Tags: java, android, multiplayer, lag

So I've been trying to think of a way to make a multiplayer quiz game where a question is displayed and the first person to buzz in (just a button on the screen) is given the opportunity to answer the question.  So with the possibility of two people buzzing in at almost the same time, what would be the best way to go about this to determine who the true first person to buzz in was?  Sockets? A service like Pusher? Bluetooth? Scoreloop? Skiller? OpenFeint? Some other solution?

Thanks for any input/examples.

---

I decided to go with bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, maybe you can still change your mind. Bluetooth is great but it is not fun if it is only close proximity gaming. It will be much more attractive if someone from South Africa could play against someone from Australia ;).

We released a new Android SDK that supports real time multiplayer (not only turn based) and this is exactly what you are looking for. You will be able to set a game and send the button press in real time. Download our new SDK at [www.skiller-games.com](http://www.skiller-games.com) and if you will have any questions post it here or send us an email to developers@skiller-games.com.

Enjoy!